# Fastest way to vectorize Gaussian CDF (or erf/erfc/etc.) on PyPy (i.e. no SciPy)

Tags: python, numpy, gaussian, pypy, cdf

I'm trying to evaluate the CDFs of lots of Gaussians on PyPy, and it's slow doing this with `math.erf`.

I don't have SciPy on PyPy so I can't use that. However, I have NumPy.

What's the fastest way for me to do this on PyPy **aside from writing my own C extension**?

Answer (score 1):

If you have numpy, you can tabulate the error function, interpolate (`np.interp` or roll-your-own), and then use numpy vectorized operations to evaluate multiple values at once.

Roughly (this is on CPython, I'm not sure if `np.interp` works in numpypy),

```
>>> import math
>>> x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 101)    # example only, better use e.g. Chebyshev nodes
>>> y = [math.erf(_) for _ in x ]
>>> xval = [-0.1, 0.4, 0.9]
>>> np.interp(xval, x, y)
array([-0.11237943,  0.42808831,  0.79690821])
```